# Can't access MongoDB database with Node library Monk, code works fine on Localhost. Really short, concise code

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, monk

So I've been dealing with this problem for some time now, and it has been really resilient considering the little lines of code. I have gone trough the documentation several times and tried many different compositions and options but it just wont work. When on localhost everything works fine, when deployed to the web the app works and I can successfully access the ./ direction which displays "Camisite ", but it gets timeout when trying to access /posts. That's all I know, if someone could provide some advice regarding how to get more information on the error that will be welcome. Just for the testing I have put the connection string directly on the code, otherwise it is on a Now secret.

So here is the code, as I said, it is pretty concise. I cut the post request part for considering it not necessary.

I already tried deleting the  `|| 'localhost/posts'` part on the connection string and leave just the string or the string inside a secret.

```
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const monk = require('monk');
const Filter = require('bad-words');
const rateLimit = require('express-rate-limit');

const filter = new Filter();
const app = express();
const db = monk('mongodb+srv://myuserexample:mypassexample@cluster0-qm9z0.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority' || 'localhost/posts');
const posts = db.get('posts');
app.enable('trust proxy');
app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.json({
        message: 'Camisite! '
    });
});

app.get('/posts', (req, res) => {
    posts
        .find()
        .then(posts => {
            res.json(posts);
        });
});

const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log('server started');
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I solved it, I had the incorrect String since it was for Node Version 3.0 or upper. And I had 2.12 even being a very recent installation. With the correct string it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to add `.catch` everywhere where you have `.then` because graceful processing of errors hepls you to cope with situation like this. Print your errors to the console with `console.error()`, and make log file, at least running your app like this:

```
node app.js >> stdout.log 2>>stderr.log
```

This will give you additional information about what happened

Comment: Thank you! I will implement so and come back with more logs. Didn't you see anything wrong with the way I'm connecting to the database?

Comment: Not really, and for my expirience, this is the wrong way when you try to say what is wrong just by looking at the code. This way gives a lot of guesses, many of which don't give anything. The best way to find the problem is it is to investigate.